# Roslyn SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(SyntaxNode node).Type returns null

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a piece of code like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace TestProject
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string text = @"
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null) { }
            if (args != null) { }
        }
    }";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(text);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(null).AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
            var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
            var root = tree.GetRoot();

            foreach (var param in root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ParameterSyntax>().ToList())
            {
                var type = param.Type;
                var name = param.Identifier;
                var typeSymbol = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(param).Type;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to be able to check if a type is a reference type. I want to do this with

```cs
typeSymbol.IsReferenceType
```

But the problem is that `semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(param).Type` returns `null`. In the same `param.Type` return correct value (`string[]`).

Any ideas why it works that way and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is just to get the parameter type, then you can change your sample to call `semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(type)`.

If you want to know everything there is to know about the parameter (does it have attributes, is it `ref`, is it `params`, etc...), then you might want to use `semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(param)`.

Comment: I've tried to use `semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(param).Type` and then get `.IsReferenceType`. And I got a very funny thing: `int` type returns `false` on `.IsValueType` and `true` on `IsReferenceType` o_O This is all very impressive, of course, but how can I normally check if this does not work... Maybe there are other ways?

Comment: That does sound strange. Feel free to update your question or ask a new question with sample code that demonstrates the behavior.